# Phonegap 2.1 for Android - Hello World App 3 errors at launch

Tags: android, cordova

I developed something with Phonegap for iOS, but this is my first trial for Android.

I created my hello world application with CLI sth like this mentioned [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html):

```
$ /path/to/cordova-android/bin/create /path/to/my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName
```

Even though I created this app in Eclipse Workspace, I needed to import it to Eclipse. I created two AVDs. One for API level 8, one for API level 16.

When I try to build, it gives me these three errors and a warning. What is wrong with my setup?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'    AndroidManifest.xml /com.example.test.testprojectname   line 20 Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'  AndroidManifest.xml /com.example.test.testprojectname   line 22 Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale'). AndroidManifest.xml /com.example.test.testprojectname   line 51 Android AAPT Problem
The import android.app.Activity is never used   testprojectname.java    /com.example.test.testprojectname/src/com/example/test  line 22 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Go to Project -> Properties -> Android and select a newer SDK (preferably the latest one), after that run Project -> Clean. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes in your AndroidManifest.xml. It sounds like you're building the app for an older SDK version that didn't have the attributes that are producing the errors. Try to set both min and target to 11 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You should always be building for the latest SDK.  It looks like your Eclipse setup is using an old version of Android (Android 2.2?).  hardwareAccelerated and xlargeScreens is from Android 3.x.  I recommend making sure your project uses the latest version fo the SDK in Eclipse.  This has nothing to do with your Android Manifest, and is actually an eclipse setting.

Answer (score 1):

By default android version is 2.1; you must right click on root folder of you project, select properties, then in android select new version; try to reload it and it wrok...

Comment: I need to target 2.3.x too. What to do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You should always be building for the latest SDK. It looks like your Eclipse setup is using an old version of Android (Android 2.2?). hardwareAccelerated and xlargeScreens is from Android 4.x. I recommend making sure your project uses the latest version of the SDK in Eclipse.

(or)

after creating your project Do the following steps

Right click your project -> properties --> change the Android target version as 4.x